# Has Wonder Woman ever killed a mortal in anger?

Tags: dc, justice-league, wonder-woman

Regularly in [JLU](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited_(animated_series)), [Wonder Woman](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/wonder-woman) appears to lose her temper and comes very close to killing someoine in anger. AFAIK she never follows through in the show.

But anywhere in canon, does she ever kill a mortal?

She decapitates [Medusa](http://wonder-woman.wikia.com/wiki/Medusa) in a baseball court, but she's not really a mortal anymore:

> The fight takes place in a baseball court and is by Ares transmitted to the world. The fight is brutal, as Diana fights blind, first by a piece of cloth, then by snake venom she pours into her own eyes. But Diana is victorious in the end as once again, Medusa is [decapitated](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/10/104108/3549882-page16.jpg).

Some examples of WW *almost* killing mortals:

> Once when she believes Superman has been killed:

> And once when some bank robbers interrupt her day off:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During *Sacrifice* (part of *Infinite Crisis*) in *[Wonder Woman #219](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_2_219)*, she snaps the neck of [Maxwell Lord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_Lord):

[image]

To be fair to her, he was mind controlling Superman at the time, but she did kill him. I'm not sure how "angry" she was tho.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Maxwell Lord [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100867/19148), Wonder Woman has killed in alternate continutities as well:

- **Flashpoint Paradox**: Wonder Woman kills Steve Trevor via hanging after he goes to save Lois Lane on new Themyscira

- **Injustice: Year 3**: Wonder Woman kills Huntress. She is upset that the Bat-family continues to fight against Superman and his regime. Huntress and Batwoman call her side tyrants. Wonder Woman wraps her lasso around Huntress's neck and gives it a tug, breaking her neck. Wonder Woman seems shocked by the neck being snapped.

[image: Lasso around Huntress's neck]
[image: Wonder Woman's reaction]

Comment: Flashpoint paradox is an alternate reality and WW is evil, not angry.

Comment: That second frame is what I came to post here :P Answer the question perfectly.